# knockout.js observables location on JavaScript window or ko object

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trouble shooting a very complex single page web application the uses knockout.js.
As part of my investigation I am trying to find out where on the window object, knockout.js puts the observable objects that are created.

Using Chrome's Console, I've search a lot of the objects off of the "`ko`" object like "`ko.virtualElements`" and the "`window`" object itself.

Am I looking in the wrong places?

Long story short, using Chrome's Console, i am wondering if I can view something like -

**window.ko.*ListOfObservables***

And **window.ko.*ListOfObservables*** would show all of the observable objects that are loaded.

NOTE: In case you are curious, I am trying to figure out why observable functionality start to fail upon different types of navigation, but *please* don't worry about that in your answer to this question unless it provides some extra insight.

Comment: Not sure if I got the question. Usually, for knockout, you need to declare the observables inside of a view model and most of the developers use "self" prefix. Maybe if you type "self." in the console you will see a list of possible observables that are already created. https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: Thanks, UserEsp. "self." does gives a list of properties (much like "this." does). So which property contains the "list of possible observables"? That is my question in a nutshell.

Answer (score 0):

There's a 2-step way you can see the currently selected DOM element's context and as such even the viewmodel if you select one of the root bound nodes.

- The first step is by selecting the DOM node in the 'elements'-tab in your browsers' developer console, Chrome and Firefox assign this to the `$0` variable in your console window.
- Secondly you can get knockout's viewmodel/context with `ko.contextFor` and at data level `ko.dataFor`

So if you combine these, select the body node in your elements tab; then type in the console:

**tldr;** `ko.dataFor($0)` and you should get what you want.

Btw, if you didn't use the global applyBindings but bound to a specific element, obviously select that one.